# ActionBarOverlayLayout how can I fixed it

Tags: android

I'm building an app with Android Studio.
I'm building a view. but I can't see the the action bar anche I can't see the Preview View.

So this is the message of Preview view:

```
Android....ActionBarOverlayLayout
```

So this is my View.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/articoli"
                android:onClick="visualizzaArticoli"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Articoli"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/order"
                android:onClick="creaOrdine"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ordini"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Mainfest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
            android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.main.nuovoOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.creaOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.mainOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.ordine.viewOrdine"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.setting.setting"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.articoli.viewArticoli"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.mainClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.viewClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.infoCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.operazioniCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.clienti.operazioniClienteDettaglio"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I fixed it ?

> EDIT
>   This is the preview in Android Studio:
>   [image]

This is the application of my Smartphone:

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please elaborate a bit more or perhaps upload a image.

Comment: I have just edit my question

Comment: Try to 'Invalidate caches & restart'.

Comment: @H.Brooks I'm try to do this but not works

Comment: Is there any error/warning messages under your preview window?

Comment: No never, if I try to start the application, I can see the application never eror